# Source/Binary Format option for java 1.7 not available in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using netbeans 8.0 and I don't get an option to change the format to java 1.7 .

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I need the option to be available for 1.7

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JDK 7. The version numbering was changed a while ago and 1.7 is actually the same as 7.